# Debugging "File not found."

Tags: error-pages

When running our main site locally, it breaks with 404 "File not found" white page. Any tips to debugging this? I've tried setting debug = 1, enable stacktrace in error document, but it still ends with only "File not found" text. Grepping for "File not found" does not show any relevant position where the code `die`s.

I'm running nginx natively and PHP inside a docker container. Still, I'd like to know very much *which* file is not found!

The PHP docker stderr shows only 404, but nginx error log shows "Primary script unknown".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing nginx configuration:

```
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
```

The problematic URL was confusing nginx since it included language prefix. The above snippet solves it.